# How do I sum a value for each date inbetween a start and end date in SQL/Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an access database of tasks that need to be completed by various resources within a team. I've already calculated the total hours per day required for each task and assigned a resource to each task in a table. A small example is shown below.

| Start Date | End Date | Hrs | Resource |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/21 | 3/1/21 | 1 | Person 1 |
| 1/1/21 | 3/1/21 | 2 | Person 2 |
| 2/1/21 | 5/1/21 | 2.5 | Person 1 |

What i want to get it to is Similar to the below, where the total hours effort each day is calculated :

| Date | Person 1 | Person 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/21 | 1 | 2 |
| 2/1/21 | 3.5 | 2 |
| 3/1/21 | 3.5 | 2 |
| 4/1/21 | 2.5 | 0 |
| 5/1/21 | 2.5 | 0 |

I'm new to SQL (self taught the basics in the last day or two), so I'm not sure of the logic to follow or the best way to achieve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a calendar table filled with dates?

Comment: I do, all dates from 1/1/21 through to 31/12/24 in the first column

Answer (score 0):

You can generate all the dates from the first column.  Then use a `join` and `group by`:

```
select d.dte,
       sum(iif(resource = 'Person 1', hrs, 0)) as person_1,
       sum(iif(resource = 'Person 2', hrs, 0)) as person_2
from (select distinct start_date as dte from t) as d join
     t
     on t.start_date <= d.dte and
        d.dte <= t.end_date
group by d.dte;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok you said you have a calendar table with date column, filled with days. So it will be a left join from that calendar table like this:

```
select c.date, p1.hrs, p2.hrs
from calendar c
  left join task p1 on p1.startDate <= c.date and c.date < p1.endDate and p1.resource = 'Person 1'
  left join task p2 on p2.startDate <= c.date and c.date < p2.endDate and p2.resource = 'Person 2'
where
  Day(c.date) = 1
```